# Keras LSTM input ValueError: Shapes are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Not sure about why I'm getting an error with my LSTM neural network. It seems to be related with the input shape.

This is my neural network architecture:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout

model = Sequential()

# Recurrent layer
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, 
           dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))

# Fully connected layer
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

# Dropout for regularization
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(y_train.nunique(), activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is how I train it:

```
history = model.fit(X_train_padded, y_train_padded, 
                    batch_size=2048, epochs=150,
                    validation_data=(X_test_padded, y_test_padded))
```

This is the shape of my input data:

```
print(X_train_padded.shape, X_test_padded.shape, y_train_padded.shape, y_test_padded.shape)
(98, 20196, 30) (98, 4935, 30) (98, 20196, 1) (98, 4935, 1)
```

This is part of my X_train_padded:

```
X_train_padded
array([[[ 2.60352379e-01, -1.66420518e-01, -3.12893162e-01, ...,
         -1.51210476e-01, -3.56188897e-01, -1.02761131e-01],
        [ 1.26103191e+00, -1.66989382e-01, -3.13025807e-01, ...,
          6.61329839e+00, -3.56188897e-01, -1.02761131e-01],
        [ 1.04418243e+00, -1.66840157e-01, -3.12994596e-01, ...,
         -1.51210476e-01, -3.56188897e-01, -1.02761131e-01],
        ...,
        [ 1.27399408e+00, -1.66998426e-01, -3.13025807e-01, ...,
          6.61329839e+00, -3.56188897e-01, -1.02761131e-01],
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Epoch 1/150
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-52422b54faa4> in <module>
----> 1 history = model.fit(X_train_padded, y_train_padded, 
      2                     batch_size=2048, epochs=150,
      3                     validation_data=(X_test_padded, y_test_padded))
...
ValueError: Shapes (None, 20196) and (None, 12) are incompatible
```

As I'm using a *LSTM* layer, I have a 3D input shape. My output layer has 12 nodes (y_train.nunique()) because I have 12 different classes in my input. Given that I have 12 classes, I'm using *softmax* as activation function in my output layer and *categorical_crossentropy* as my loss function.

**EDIT:**

Let me try to explain better my [dataset](https://xeek.ai/challenges/force-well-logs/data):

I'm dealing with geological wells. My samples are different types of sedimentary rocks layers, where the features are the rocks' properties (such as gammay ray emission) and the label is the rock type (such as limestone). One of my features is the depth of the layer.

The idea behing using an LSTM in this case, is to consider the depth of a well as a sequence. So that the previous sedimentary layer (rock) helps to predict the next sedimentary layer (rock).

How did I get to my input shape:

I have a total of **98** wells in my dataset. I splitted the dataset: `X_train_init, X_test_init, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)`. The well with the most samples (layers) has, in the training set, **20196** samples. The wells that didn't have this many samples, I padded them with zeros so that they had **20196** samples. The well with the most samples (layers) has, in the test set, **4935** samples. The wells that didn't have this many samples, I padded them with zeros so that they had **4935** samples. Removing the *well* feature and the *depth* feature (among other features) I ended up with **30** features total. My `y_train` and `y_test` has only **1** column which represents the label.

I guess that my problem is actually getting this dataset to work in a LSTM. Most of the examples that I see, don't have 98 different time series, they just have one. I'm not really sure about how to deal with 98 different time series (wells).

Comment: Since you have used, `categorical_crossentropy`, your labels should be one_hot encoded. Since you have 1 label for each sample, likely it's not one-hot encoded. So, you should use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function.

Comment: I have 12 labels (classes). Indeed, they are not one-hot-encoded, they are in just one single column. The shape `X_train_padded.shape` (98, 20196, 30) means 98 samples, 20196 timestamps and 30 features. The shape `y_train_padded.shape` (98, 20196, 1) means 98 samples, 20196 timestamps and 1 ground truth column (having value ranging from 0 to 11, representing the 12 classes). Each one of the 98 samples have 20196 timestamps and each timestamp has its own class. Thus, I don't have 1 label for each sample, I have multiple labels in each of my 98 samples.

Comment: Since your y_train is a sequence, you need to set `return_sequences=True` in your LSTM layer.

Comment: Time steps for `x_train` and `x_test` should be same. Here it is `20196` for `x_train` and `4935` for `x_test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work. Except for the batch size, every other input dimension should be the same. Also, your inputs dimensions are all going crazy. for example -

```
print(X_train_padded.shape, # (98, 20196, 30)
X_test_padded.shape, # (98, 4935, 30)
y_train_padded.shape, # (98, 20196, 1)
y_test_padded.shape) # (98, 4935, 1)
```

from what I see the first dimension is supposed to represent the total number of samples (in x_train,y_train, and x_test,y_test) but in your case, the total samples are represented by the second dimension. The first dimension should be in second place. So as to say the dimensions should

```
print(X_train_padded.shape, # (20196, 98, 30)
X_test_padded.shape, # (4935, 98, 30)
y_train_padded.shape, # (20196, 98, 1)
y_test_padded.shape) # (4935, 98, 1)
```

This will put everything in the right place. You just need to look at how you
came to the wrong dimensions and change that part.

Comment: @Matheus Schaly Did you check whether this solves your issue ?

Comment: I'm in a hurry lately. I managed to reshape my input according to Abhishek answer. But I'm struggling with the layers' arguments. For example, what is the input_shape of the LSTM; I have 12 classes, which is given by y_train.nunique(), but that seems to be causing a problem as well.

Comment: @MatheusSchaly If the answer helped and solved your question then kindly upvote. As for your current issue, the LSTM takes an input of shape `(batch_size, _, _, _)` so you just need to batch your data. you have a total of `20196` samples in train and `4935` in test, you can just use a batch size from 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, etc and use `expand_dim` to add another dimension. Also almost always explicitly define the number of output neurons. like this ```model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))```

Comment: @MatheusSchaly to add another dimension you can use the `Reshape` layer of Keras and change the shape to `(batch_size, 1, 98, 30)` just before feeding to the `LSTM layer`. for reference - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekPrajapat. I'll look more into it and get back here asap with information about how I managed to completely solve my issue.