# How to solve ValueError in LSTM input?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have the training and testing `numpy` arrays in the following shapes

```
TrainX = (1234, 50, 50) Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> # 1234 arrays of 50 by 50 floats
TrainY = (1234, 2) Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
# TrainY was one column of binary class 0 or 1. Converted it through to_categorical()

TestX = (123, 50, 50) Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
TestY = (123, 2) Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I use the following code for the LSTM,

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(TrainX.shape[1], TrainX.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

model.compile("adam", "categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(
    TrainX,
    TrainY,
    batch_size=24,
    epochs=48,
    validation_data=[np.asarray(TestX).all(), np.asarray(TestY).all()],
    class_weight=classweights,#calculated class weights
    verbose=2,
)
```

1. First I used `TrainX` and `TrainY` but got an error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
2. Based on this [Keras LSTM input ValueError: Shapes are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323793/keras-lstm-input-valueerror-shapes-are-incompatible), I used `np.asarray(TrainX)`. But got the same error.
3. So I added `np.asarray(TrainX).all()` one time and `np.asarray(TrainX).any()` another time. But got a different value error: `ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>`
4. Finally, I tried `pandas.DataFrame(TrainX)` for input. But it showed the following error, `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1234, 50, 50)`

trace back of the errors 1 and 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\...\main.py", line 73, in <module>
    lmodel.lstm(TrainX, TestX, TrainY, TestY)
  File "C:\Users\...\llmodel.py", line 65, in lstm
    model.fit(
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1137, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1394, in get_data_handler
    return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1169, in __init__
    self._configure_dataset_and_inferred_steps(strategy, x, steps_per_epoch,
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1177, in _configure_dataset_and_inferred_steps
    if class_weight:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: `np.asarray(TrainX).all()` You don't need this. Just pass them into the `fit()` function as arrays. 
 `np.asarray(TestX).all(), np.asarray(TestY).all()` Just like inputs, this is just arrays - `TestX, TestY`. Shouldn't your Y be somewhat one dimension? I think that's why #1 is happening. Something like shape (1234, 1). Because that one element can still be any value. Unless you're assigning two values from Y?

Comment: Sounds like you need to try a few more random fixes :(  The key to debugging is to first understand the problem.  Fixes come later.  For a start show the complete error, with traceback (for the first error)

Comment: @Djinn Yeah, I corrected the post. I listed the things I tried 1-4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log suggests that the problem is in your `class_weight` argument. According to [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), this argument should be

> Optional **dictionary** mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

which should be something like

```
class_weights = {0: 0.75, 1: 1.25}
```

if you want to assign a weight of 0.75 and 1.25 to class 0 and 1, respectively.

From the log, I suspect that instead of passing such a dictionary, you passed a numpy array of shape `(n_samples, n_classes)` as `class_weight`, which is inappropriate.